# Best Practice; Programmatically detecting keywords from text

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to extract numbers from a string (email) based on keywords.
There are a couple of difficulties here;

- The numbers we are looking for in our system are Always 8 characters, but the senders could be neglecting the preprocessing "0" and instead of sending 01234567 they will send us 1234567.
- There are other numbers that could be matched as valid numbers, like Phonenumbers, and are known in our system, therefore we have decided to detect preprocessing keywords like "casenumber: " and other variants.
- last but not least, the sender could send "casenumber: 1234567" but he could also send "casenumbers: 1234567, 7654321" or any variant of that. (devider ; or , or . or : etc.)

An example text:

```
Hi!

Hereby I would like to confirm that I will be present at the meeting about casenumber: 1234567 and 7654321.
Can you confirm that you have received this email?

Kind regards,
Random person
```

What I have tried to use is a regex match that searches for a list of keywords, including "casenumber:" and than adding after that all possible solutions, but this only works for 1 case number, the second one or third and so on will not be found.

Code language used: C#

Current code:

```
 Regex.Matches(checkString, keyword + @"[ +;:,.\r\n\t]*[BL0123456789][0-9]+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase )
```

This my current regex, it uses Regex.Matches and checks generally on global. It does match when the text has "casenumber: 12345678 and casenumber: 87654321" but not when its comma seperated.

Comment: Could you show us the code you're using for the regex?

Comment: "The numbers we are looking for in our system are Always 8 characters, but the senders could be neglecting the preprocessing "0" and instead of sending 01234567 they will send us 1234567."  Then they aren't always 8 characters...

Comment: @Amy " in our system are Always 8 characters" as said after that, we preprocess it with "0" when its not 8 characters.

Comment: @Gavin I use `Regex.Matches(checkString, keyword + @"[ +;:,.\r\n\t]*[BL0123456789][0-9]+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase )` as regex checker, Regex.Matches checks generally on global.
It does match when the text has "casenumber: 12345678 and casenumber: 87654321" but not when its comma seperated.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I am asking a question based on the rules, and still get downvoted?

Comment: Post the regex in the OP, please. It's easier for others to follow when they stumble upon your post. :)

Comment: @Hank done :)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested my variation of your original RegEx and have adapted it to work with the dividers, even the Oxford comma:

```
Regex.Matches(checkstring, keyword + @"([ +;:,.\r\n\t]*[BL0123456789][0-9]+(([ -_=*&/+;:,.\r\n\t]|en)+[BL0123456789][0-9]+)*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Hey Hank!
Thank you for your answer, I have found your the best for my cases, I have modified it a bit, we have had +/- 900.000 emails over the past year with the old regex and it failed for more than 1 casenumber or certain characters some people use - or & for a divider, it ended up being:
([ +;:,.\r\n\t]*[BL0123456789][0-9]+(([ -_=*&/+;:,.\r\n\t]|en)+[BL0123456789][0-9]+)*)

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @JpHouten I edited my answer so it's easier to find for those who stumble upon this.

Answer (score 1):

This regex:

```
(^| |.|;|:|,)[Cc]asenumbers? ?: ?[0-9]{7,8} ?(([;:,\.]|and) ?[0-9]{7,8})*
```

I think will catch the all your cases, just use it in some function (read C# docs) which find all the matched cases. It takes care about some typos like missing spaces. I would strongly recommend try to figure it out more possibilities in which your users can put those case numbers and match it in this regex.

Comment: Hey Madry, thank you for your answer, thanks to you and Hank I have figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to select the full sequence(s) of numbers and then match single numbers in the extracted string(s).

Some assumptions should be made about the structure of the sequence, but since we are talking about emails freely written by humans we won't probably be able to build an expression working in 100% of the cases.

Knowing that the sequence starts with "casenumber" is useful, but not knowing where it ends might be a problem: stopping at linebreak or full stop would work for your example, but not with:

> I will be present at the meeting about casenumber: 1234567, if you have other questions contact me at 9876543.

Without a known sequence ender, we can try to recognize separators: according to your specification they can vary, but we could assume that a list of casenumbers will not have more than one word between two numbers (as I said, not perfect, but should work in most cases).

For example, you could use this regex:
[casenumber(\s*[^\s\d]+\s*\d{7,8})+](https://regex101.com/r/cshyL0/1)

With this we match casenumber (the plural form is also matched by the rest of the expression) followed by an alternating sequence of non-number/7-8digits, with possible spaces between them.

You should try this expression on your data and adapt it to your needs (I repeat: you won't have a guaranteed perfect solution, but you can make it work as best as possible on your data).

Once you have extracted the sequences, a simple regex like `\d+` will be able to extract the numbers from them.

Comment: You could [accept 2-words delimiters](https://regex101.com/r/cshyL0/6), probably still an acceptable assumption.